# Method format within Angular2 model class

Tags: javascript, class, angular, typescript

I have a basic model class (not a component):

```
export class catModel { 
 constructor(public name: string) { }
 getName: string {
  return this.name.toUpperCase();
 }
}
```

Now I'll try and use this model in a component like this:

```
feline: catModel = {name: 'simba' };
```

...when I compile I get the following error:

> Type '{ name: string }' is not assignable to type 'catModel'.  Property 'getName' is missing in type '{ name: string }'

As soon as remove the getName function from the catModel it works fine, why won't it let me add a method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because Typescript uses a [structural type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system). As stated in the [TypeScript docs: Type Compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html)

> The basic rule for TypeScript’s structural type system is that `x` is compatible with `y` if `y` has at least the same members as `x`

"same members" means properties *and* methods. If you think about this reasoning, it makes perfect sense. By typing something as `CarModel`, you are making a guarantee to anyone using it that it will behave like a `CarModel`. If you don't have a `getName` in your object literal, then it *can't* be a `CarModel`, as it doesn't follow the contract.

Read the second link above. It's a great reference document.

---

<sub>Probably not what the main concern in your post is about, but the obvious solution is to just construct an instance of the class `new CarModel('simba')`.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

This should resolve your problem,

```
export class catModel { 

  name:string;    //<-----here

  constructor(public name: string) { }

  getName: string {
    return this.name.toUpperCase();
  }

}
```