# Property toggleEdit is missing in type Employee", but it is a method, what to do? Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, compiler-errors, angular2-components

I have an Employee component -

```
export class EmployeeComponent{
name:string;
    isEditOn:boolean;

    constructor(){}

     toggleEdit():void{
        this.isEditOn = !this.isEditOn;
    }
}
```

And EmployeeList Component like this -

```
export class EmployeeListComponent{
    employees: Employee[] = [];

    AddNewEmployee(){
        this.employees.push({name:"New Employee", isEditOn:false});
    }
}
```

I am getting error on the line where I am trying to push the new Employee in the list.

> Property 'toggleEdit' is missing in type '{ name: string; isEditOn: false; }'.

But isn't it a method? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Show the class/Interface Employee. Perhaps you are missing some required properties in the object you add to employees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
export class Employee {

    constructor(public name: string, public isEditOn: boolean){}

     toggleEdit():void{
        this.isEditOn = !this.isEditOn;
    }
}
```

```js
export class EmployeeListComponent{
    employees: Employee[] = [];

    AddNewEmployee(){
        this.employees.push(new Employee("New Employee", false));
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is link to better understand what is happening https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39433286/method-format-within-angular2-model-class?rq=1

Comment: Thanks. I already figured this but thanks for confirming Yoni!!